# How to get the earliest date of the lastmodifier?

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I choose to pickup the earliest date and also the same row of another column which is lastmodifier. Is this possible to get the same row data just like vlookup. when I MIN(DATE) and will lookup the other column same row 's value.

I have try to get the min(date) and group by lastmodifier. However, I don't know which lastmodifier does the script pick.

```
with CASECODESTATS (ORDBATCH,PO,EARLIEST,OPERATOR,count1,count2) as 
(
select substr(code,1,15),substr(code,1,14),MIN(LSTUPDTIME),LSTMODIFIER,COUNT(c.code) ,0
from casecode c
where c.state='REVIEWED'
group by substr(code,1,15),LSTMODIFIER,substr(code,1,14)


union all 

select substr(code,1,15),substr(code,1,14),MIN(LSTUPDTIME),LSTMODIFIER,0,COUNT(c.code)
from casecode c
where c.state ='WAREHOUSE RECEIVE'
group by substr(code,1,15),LSTMODIFIER,substr(code,1,14)
 )

select ORDBATCH ORBATCH,sum(count1) REVIEWED ,sum(count2) WAREHOUSERECIEVE,MIN(EARLIEST) EARLIESTDATE,OPERATOR LSTMODIFIER,PO ORDERNUM from CASECODESTATS

where 1=1
group by ORDBATCH,OPERATOR,PO

order by ORDBATCH
```

I want to select the 1st lastmodifier in every ordernumber.

Comment: "Get the **earliest** date of the **last**modifier" - just by reading that sentence, looks like `min(date_column), max(lastmodifier_column) group by everything_else`. I guess sample data would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, sample data and expected output would be very helpful in such question. But I think you need this:

```
select substr(code, 1, 2) ordbatch, substr(code, 1, 1) ordernum, min(lstupdtime) earliest, 
       min(lstmodifier) keep (dense_rank first order by lstupdtime) lstmodifier,
       count(case state when 'REVIEWED' then 1 end) reviewed,
       count(case state when 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE' then 1 end) warehouse
  from casecode 
  where state in ('REVIEWED', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE')
  group by substr(code,1,2), substr(code,1,1)
```

First: you do not need `union`, use conditional `count` with `case`. But the answer to your main question is `min ... keep ... first`. It finds value of some column (`lstmodifier`) where value of the other column (`lstupdtime`) is the lowest. `min` means that if two operators meets criteria we have to pick someone so we take first alphabetically. I don't know what you want to do in such situation, depending on that different solutions are posibble, for instance with `rank` and `listagg`.

Here is the example:

```
with casecode(code, state, lstupdtime, lstmodifier) as (
    select 'A1', 'REVIEWED',          date '2018-12-25', 'Clark' from dual union all
    select 'A1', 'OTHER',             date '2018-12-25', 'Clark' from dual union all
    select 'A1', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE', date '2018-12-25', 'Clark' from dual union all
    select 'A1', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE', date '2018-12-24', 'Jones' from dual union all
    select 'B1', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE', date '2018-12-25', 'Clark' from dual union all
    select 'B2', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE', date '2018-12-25', 'Clark' from dual 
  )
select substr(code, 1, 2) ordbatch, substr(code, 1, 1) ordernum, min(lstupdtime) earliest, 
       min(lstmodifier) keep (dense_rank first order by lstupdtime) lstmodifier,
       count(case state when 'REVIEWED' then 1 end) reviewed,
       count(case state when 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE' then 1 end) warehouse
  from casecode 
  where state in ('REVIEWED', 'WAREHOUSE RECEIVE')
  group by substr(code,1,2), substr(code,1,1)
```

I used shorter `substr` for `code` manipulation to make things clear, use 14 and 15 instead. Jones is picked, because his `lstupdtime` is the lowest:

```
ORDBATCH ORDERNUM EARLIEST    LSTMODIFIER   REVIEWED  WAREHOUSE
-------- -------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
A1       A        2018-12-24  Jones                1          2
B1       B        2018-12-25  Clark                0          1
B2       B        2018-12-25  Clark                0          1
```